# Combine Metric and Dimension In Formula (Datastudio)

Tags: sql, looker-studio

I am trying to figure out how to create a column where...

```
clicks * (CASE
  When Date <= "Jan 1,  2020" then 5
  when Date >= "Jan 2, 2020" then 10
end)
```

But the error I am getting is this:

> Sorry, calculated fields can't mix metrics (aggregated values) and
> dimensions (non-aggregated values). Please check the aggregation types
> of the fields used in this formula

Date is the dimension and clicks are the metric.

What the result should look like:

> ```
>     DATE ----- CLICKS --------- RESULT
> Jan 1, 2020     100              500
> Jan 1, 2020      40              200
> Jan 1, 2020      10               50
> Jan 2, 2020      30              300
> Jan 1, 2020      90              900
> ```

Is there a way to change Date into a Metric, or is there another way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap the CASE inside a MAX you'll get back a number and you'll avoid the error.

```
    clicks * MAX(
     (CASE
      WHEN Date <= "Jan 1,  2020" then 5
      WHEN Date >= "Jan 2, 2020" then 10
      END))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the way the case statement is written is fine. You may need to check the data type for the Date dimension, and it should be in the "Date" format so that data studio knows to treat that data as a Date and then write the date in the case statement in the same format as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
  clicks * MAX(
     (CASE
      WHEN Date <= "Aug 15,  2021" then 2
      WHEN Date > "Aug 15, 2021" then 4
      END))
```

This worked!